# c++ - Clearing an Accumulator in a 'while' Loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

This code needed to do 4 things:

- Enter the number of sales items
- Enter the price of each sales item
- Enter tax percentage
- Option to run again

I have completed all these requirements, but my only issue comes in when the code repeats. I save the total item value in an accumulator within the 'while' post-test loop. When the program loops, it doesn't clear the accumulator, and continues to just add any new values on top of my old total value.

(E.g. If my first run of the code had a total of 20$, and the repeated run has a total of 30$, it will display my total price being 50$)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){

char answer = ' ';
int saleItems = 0;
double itemValue = 0.0;
double titemValue = 0.0;
double taxPerc = 0.0;

do {
    cout << "How many sales items do you have? : ";
    cin >> saleItems;

    for (int x = 1; x <= saleItems; x += 1){
        cout << "Enter in the value of sales item " << x << " : $";
        cin >> itemValue;
        titemValue += itemValue;
    } 

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter in the sales tax percentage(Enter 10 for 10%): ";
    cin >> taxPerc;
    cout << endl << endl;

    double saleTax = titemValue * (taxPerc / 100);
    double grandTotal = titemValue + saleTax;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

    cout << "********************************************" << endl;
    cout << "********  S A L E S  R E C E I P T  ********" << endl;
    cout << "********************************************" << endl;
    cout << "**                                        **" << endl;
    cout << "**                                        **" << endl;
    cout << "**                                        **" << endl;
    cout << "**                                        **" << endl;
    cout << "**  Total Sales            $" << setw(9) << titemValue << "     **" << endl;
    cout << "**  Sales Tax              $" << setw(9) << saleTax << "     **" << endl;
    cout << "**                          ----------    **" << endl;
    cout << "**  Grand Total            $" << setw(9) << grandTotal << "     **" << endl;
    cout << "**                                        **" << endl;
    cout << "**                                        **" << endl;
    cout << "********************************************" << endl << endl << endl;

    cout << "Do you want to run this program again? (Y/N):";
    cin >> answer;
    answer = toupper(answer);
    cout << endl << endl;

    } while (answer == 'Y');


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You initialise the variables at the beginning of the program. You run your program once, but execute the loop in it multiple times. So if you want your variables to be initialised at the start of each iteration, that's where you should initialise them to 0.0. Although it's a good practice to also leave the initialisation at the declaration like you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the value of titemValue inside the loop, but it's set outside of the loop. Change

```
char answer = ' ';
int saleItems = 0;
double itemValue = 0.0;
double titemValue = 0.0;
double taxPerc = 0.0;

do {
    cout << "How many sales items do you have? : ";
    cin >> saleItems;
```

to

```
char answer = ' ';
int saleItems = 0;
double itemValue = 0.0;
double titemValue; // (changed)
double taxPerc = 0.0;

do {
    titemValue = 0.0; // (new)
    cout << "How many sales items do you have? : ";
    cin >> saleItems;
```

You don't necessarily need to change the first line, but no sense in setting its value to the same thing twice. AFAIK some compilers may optimize it away if you leave in the double initialization anyway, though. Some will not, such as Visual Studio in default Debug configuration settings.

Comment: *but no sense in setting its value to the same thing twice.* I think it's a good practice to always initialize a variable.YMMV.

Comment: Probably depends on the application, i.e. how concerned you are about run speed vs. potential bugs. If you have a very large array which is initialized twice, and you're sure it's initialized twice, and it's taking a long time to initialize, I could definitely see exceptions being made for such cases. In this case, I removed it because it's obvious, but I would leave it in if it weren't or if I expected a co-developer to potentially change something that would break it (e.g. class members I typically always initialize immediately in the ctor, even if they're initialized again later).

Comment: Compiler will come along, see that `double titemValue = 0.0;`'s assignment had absolutely no effect on the program and trim it out. On the other hand, if it does matter and you have a bug, it's a lot easier to trap 0.0 than some random crap that happened to be in RAM.